# Azure Storage -- How to find access keys on the Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

According to: [Manage storage account access keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-keys-manage?tabs=azure-portal), it's supposed to be under Settings -> Access Keys but my Azure portal does not have this option.

Comment: azure console? are you refering to the portal?

Comment: Yes -- I mean portal https://portal.azure.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find your Storage Account access keys in the Azure portal (timeframe October 2021), go to `Security + networking` -> `Access keys`.

[image: Storage access keys]

**EDIT:**
The documentation has been updated with the current situation.

Answer (score 1):

It has been moved under **`Settings - > Security + networking -> Access keys.`**

To find any settings for any service, use the search tab on the blade.[image]